# About android pull notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, pull

It is possible to create 2 pull notification ( 2 broadcast receiver and 2 service) in 1 application??

Lets say i have 2 events, A and B
Event A i would like to pull the data from server every 12 hours and event B every 1 hour with different data from event A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is. You can start from here: [Managing Multiple BroadcastReceivers](https://www.mobomo.com/2011/06/android-managing-multiple-broadcast-receivers/)

It's also recommended to show your code to understand how are you facing the problem, otherwise we could think you want StackOverflow to make your app for you.